# set debounce in ionic searchbox with angular not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to let users make a search to the database to pull results by searching in a textbox and I don't want the API to be called whenever a variable is inserted in the textbox but wait for 3 seconds before the call is made to the API.
I'm using debounce but it's not working

```
<ion-searchbar
[(ngModel)]="userSearch"
          [debounce]="4000"
           (ionInput)="liveSearch($event)"
           placeholder="Search for Politics, Entertainment, Sports..."
></ion-searchbar>
```

JS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../services/news-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {

  userSearch: any;
  searchResults: any= [];

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) {}

  liveSearch() {
    this.newsService.searchNews(this.userSearch).subscribe(data => {
      this.searchResults = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change `(ionInput)="liveSearch($event)"` to `(ionChange)="liveSearch($event)"`, since the debounce property only changes the `ionChange` behaviour.

Comment: Important: With Ionic 7 (er even earlier) this isn't correct anymore and might significantly change what you would expect from the ion-searchbar. See the documentation: "The ionChange event is fired for <ion-searchbar> elements when the user modifies the element's value. Unlike the ionInput event, **the onChange event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value**."